# Is http errors always visible in console?

Tags: angular, http, error-handling

Everything works fine. I am just wondering if the red error messages in the console should exists event though I do handle the errors?

[image]

When I am posting something and saving to a Mongo collection the system is designed to return an 409 error whenever there is a duplicate key. I handle it like this on client side:

```
  registerUser() {
    this.auth.registerUser(this.user).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        if (err.status == 409) {
          this.snackBar.open(err.error.message, 'Luk', {
            duration: 3000,
          })
          return EMPTY;
        } else {
          return throwError(err);
        }
      })
    )
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        },
        err => {}
      )
  }
```

So the question is - even though I handle errors will the errors allways end up in the console?